# Tensorflow: raise ValueError("GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.") while using tf.image and keras to do data augmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `TensorFlow` and `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()` to generate synthetic data for balancing the sample size for all classes before training. I got error message as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_augmentation.py", line 100, in <module>
    run(fish_class_aug_fold[i])
  File "data_augmentation.py", line 93, in run
    data_augmentation(img_handle, fish_class, aug_fold)
  File "data_augmentation.py", line 52, in data_augmentation
    img = session.run(img)
  File "/Users/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1039, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Users/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1017, in _run_fn
self._extend_graph()
  File "/Users/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1061, in _extend_graph
add_shapes=self._add_shapes)
  File "/Users/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2154, in _as_graph_def
    raise ValueError("GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.")
ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.
```

Here is my code:

```
def data_augmentation(img_handle, fish_class, nb_fold):
"""
This function is to generate synthetic pics for each class
parameters:
img_handle: a path for each input img
class: name of each class in this problem
nb_fold: an integer which indicates the number of folds that should run for each class
for generating the same number of images for each class.
"""

img = cv2.imread(img_handle)
# randomly adjust the hue of the img
img = tf.image.random_hue(img, max_delta=0.3)

# randomly adjust the contrust
img = tf.image.random_contrast(img,lower=0.3, upper=1.0)

# randomly adjust the brightness
img = tf.image.random_brightness(img, max_delta=0.2)

# randomly adjust the saturation
img = tf.image.random_saturation(img, lower=0.0, upper=2.0)

with tf.Session() as session:
    # this output is np.ndarray
    img = session.run(img)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=45,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')

x = img.reshape((1,) + img.shape)  # this is a Numpy array with shape (1, 3, height, width)

i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1, save_to_dir = data_dir+class, \
                            save_prefix=class, save_format='jpg'):
    i += 1
    if i > nb_fold-1:
        break
```

My idea is to randomly change the input image by using 'tf.image' function, and use the output of `tf.image` as input of the `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()` to generate synthetic images before training.

I think the problem came from the `session.run(img)`. 
I don't understand why it happens and how to solve it.

Any idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What are the dimensions of your images? It could be that they are too large.

Comment: @RobertValencia  2D image, most of them are 1280 by 720. Is it too large to use tf.image?

Comment: The error indicated that it is not related to the given code but to the GraphDef being loaded. How do you get it into the program?https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/#graphdef

Comment: @Klaus D. I kinda figure that it is not the code problem; however the same error occurs after 3 hours of running the code. So I am confused. I used `tf.Graph().as_default()` to override default graph, the same error still occurred. Any idea why it happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1280 x 720* might be **too large**. I had the same problem before when I used similar dimensions for image/video recognition. Try to **downsize** your images down by a **factor of 4**, then **try again**:

```
columns = 1280/4
rows = 720/4

img = cv2.imread(img_handle)
img = cv2.resize(img, (columns, rows))
# add the rest of your code here
```

**Also**, try using **different default graphs** for each session to prevent the graph from expanding beyond the 2 GB limit:

```
with tf.Session() as session, tf.Graph().as_default():
    img = session.run(img)
```

Finally, you might also be interested in using **TensorBoard** for visualizing graphs: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz

Comment: I certainly need to resize the image to smaller size before training. However, Why would image size be a problem for this session.run() function?

Comment: I would try to resize image while generating new images. Thank you!

Comment: The error occurred when the code run through about 2000 images. I have another 2000 images to go.

Comment: On second thought, maybe it has something to do with your default graphs. Can you try the updated answer?

Comment: @ Robert Valencia. I am running the code with adding `tf.Graph().as_default()`. I will let you know the results soon. As I read from the TensorFlow documentation [tf.Graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/Graph), " the tf.Graph.as_default context manager, which overrides the current default graph for the lifetime of the context". I don't understand why overriding is necessary. I mean, after running session.run(img)session.run(img)session.run(img), the session should be closed. The rest code has nothing to do with it. Why is the default graph is a problem here?

Comment: I tried adding `tf.Graph().as_default()`, the same error occurs. With that trial, I did not resize the image to smaller ones. It could be due to the large size of images. Not sure yet.

Comment: Can you try doing both. If it still doesn't work, I'll delete my answer. Thanks

Comment: working on it. I have a large dataset, which takes a long time to run.

Comment: still running here. At least it goes further for now without errors . My computer is kinda slow. I observed that it was quite fast at beginning, and it is getting slower and slower. Anyway, still running. I'll let you know as soon as it is done.

Comment: I did it. I have 3,800 images of size 1280 by 720. I resized them to 256 by 144, and generated 11216 images in total. The whole process took 1275 mins, which is insane. Although the code works, there must be something unreasonable occurred here. It seems that the computational graph is increasing with running; however, I could not figure out why it is the case.

Comment: @Jundong I see. That's good. Training takes a lot of time especially on normal computers. I myself rent machine learning PaaS like Paperspace cause it will take way too long on my laptop. I thought using new default graphs for each session would prevent the graph from expanding beyond the limit. Should I delete my answer, or did it help solve your problem? If it helped, please accept/upvote the answer to help others find it too.

Comment: I think using resize the image helps. I also used `tf.Graph().as_default()`, but I am not sure if this line helps as well. Probably   `tf.Graph().as_default()` does not help, since my code also failed if not using resize. So, yes, it helps. Thank you. Can I ask you one more question? Do you know how to check or visualize 'computational graph' in TensorFlow? Thank you.

Comment: You might find TensorBoard useful, which can visualize graphs: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out!